# escape a string for use in java regex query

Tags: java, regex

I have a string stored in a variable which contains square brackets. I want to use this string as part of a regex statement, and have found I need to double escape the square brackets to get the result I need.

The string is of the form:

```
String str = "myVar[100]";
```

and the regex is used to parse a text file and look for the value between quotes after this string, i.e. the value of the variable:

```
if(str.contains("[")) {
  str.replace("[", "\\\\[");
  str.replace("]", "\\\\]");
}
```

Regex:

```
Pattern q = Pattern.compile(str + " *?= *?\"(.*)\";");   
Matcher n = q.matcher(line);
while (n.find()) {
  System.out.println(n.group(0));
}
```

But it's not finding any matches. Am I escaping the backslashes correctly?

Comment: Don't build the escaping yourself, use https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#quote(java.lang.String)

Comment: You don't want to escape a slash, right?

Comment: @RomanC right, i want to insert two backslashes before the brackets. Per Roberts comment above, may not need to do it at all?

Comment: @Robert it works! put that as an answer and i'll mark it as such. you've no idea how long ive been wrangling with this. So simple, classic!